# How to implement Array.Copy in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, copy

I need to implement the Array.Copy(Array sourceArray, int sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, int destinationIndex, int length) in a function.

The array it gets is a char[] array here is my implementation but it doesn't work:

```
private char[] ArrayCopier(char[] chars, int startIndex, int length)
        {
            char[] NewArray = new char[length];
            int index = 0;

            for (int i = startIndex; i < length; i++)
            {
                NewArray[index] = chars[i];
            }

            return NewArray;
        }
```

Comment: You forgot to increment `index` counter.

Comment: @DavidPivovar Ahh thanks, but still doesn't work :(

Comment: And `i < (length + startIndex)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your for loop you need index++; otherwise it will put every char in the first position of your new array.

Also I'd check that you don't go beyond the bounds of your source array.

So:

```
private char[] ArrayCopier(char[] chars, int startIndex, int length)
        {
            char[] NewArray = new char[length];
            int index = 0;

            for (int i = startIndex; (i < length)&&(i<chars.length); i++)
            {
                NewArray[index] = chars[i];
                index++;

            }

            return NewArray;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```cs
private char[] ArrayCopier(char[] chars, int startIndex, int length)
{
    // make sure startIndex is within the bounds of the given array
    if (startIndex < 0 || startIndex >= chars.Length)
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

    // if necessary, recalculate length to be within the array boundaries
    if (startIndex + length > chars.Length)
        length = chars.Length - startIndex;

    var result = new char[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        result[i] = chars[i + startIndex];

    return result;
}
```